# discord.py bot works locally but not when hosted on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

I've created a discord role assign bot in Python and running the code locally functions as expected.

```
#import discord lib
import discord
#import commands from discord lib
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

#start event and check Bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

#upon detecting a reaction event assign the role which matches the reaction emoji
#see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#rawreactionactionevent
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id

    #check if the message id matches the message id of the "assign your role!" message in discord
    if message_id == 123456789:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        #if the name of the reaction emoji is "League" theen assign the "League bois discord role
        if payload.emoji.name == "League":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="League bois")
        else:
        #set role variable to the name of the reaction emoji
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            #debugging
            print("member name: "+str(member))
            print("emoji name: "+str(payload.emoji.name))
            print("role name: "+str(role))
            
            #user id from event payload
            print(payload.user_id)
            #use user id from payload to search for member
            member2 = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            #print the search result
            print(member2)
            print(str(payload.member))
            
            #end debugging
            if member is not None:
                #add the role
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("Member not found.")
        else:
            print("Role not found.")
```

I'm using Github Desktop to push to Heroku.
Debugging in Visual Studio Code returns expected output:

```
Bot is ready.
member name: user#1234
emoji name: League
role name: League bois
987654321
user#1234
done
```

But debugging results from Heroku logs show that its failing to find the member.

```
2020-09-27T15:21:56.088983+00:00 app[worker.1]: member name: None
2020-09-27T15:21:56.089001+00:00 app[worker.1]: emoji name: League
2020-09-27T15:21:56.089007+00:00 app[worker.1]: role name: League bois
2020-09-27T15:21:56.089008+00:00 app[worker.1]: 987654321
2020-09-27T15:21:56.089009+00:00 app[worker.1]: None
2020-09-27T15:21:56.089012+00:00 app[worker.1]: Member not found.
```

I believe line 41 in my first code snip is failing when running from Heroku.

```
 member2 = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
```

I note that `print(str(payload.member))` returns the member in Heroku logs for REACTION_ADD event type. However, I would like for the user to be able to remove their role by removing their reaction and payload.member is only available if event_type is REACTION_ADD, not REACTION_REMOVE.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Hello daz, and welcome to SO! The thing with Heroku is that it is generally meant for websites, meaning it's underpowered for bots. It also has minimal dependency source control, which means it may not be able to get certain bindings to C. This may be the cause of your problem. If you want free hosting and don't plan on trying to expand the bot to other servers, then use IBM. It's a free hosting alternative which doesn't need a credit card. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/free/) is the link.